# Copying specific frames from one action to another ( python )

Tags: python, animation, keyframes, actions

I'd like to take specific keyframes from an action ( say 33 to 66 ) and copy them over to another action.

I know I can copy the entire action and just delete the peripheral frames, but that can potentially take long for actions that have a lot of frames in them.

I'd be doing this to a blank action.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Numpy action slicer.**

Script to roll thru the fcurves of an action and create a new one based on a new frame range. A condition to shift the frames of the copy is added.

> I know I can copy the entire action and just delete the peripheral
> frames

The rub here is that copying the action using `Action.copy()` will AFAIK bring along all the fcurve modifiers and other stuff I have not added in here.

Test script, added a timer wrapper for testing.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

def time_it(func):
    import time
    def wrapper(action, start_frame, end_frame, **kw):
        print("-" * 44)
        print("In:", action.name, "frame_range", action.frame_range[:])
        print("Fcurves", len(action.fcurves))
        print("Keyframes", sum(len(fc.keyframe_points) for fc in action.fcurves))
        t1 = time.time()
        copy = func(action, start_frame, end_frame, **kw)
        t2 = time.time()

        print("Out:", copy.name, "frame_range", copy.frame_range[:])
        print("Fcurves", len(copy.fcurves))
        print("Keyframes", sum(len(fc.keyframe_points) for fc in copy.fcurves))
  
        print("Elapsed time", (t2 - t1))
        print("-" * 44)
        return copy
    return wrapper

@time_it    
def action_slice(action, start_frame, end_frame, shift=True): 
    copy = bpy.data.actions.new(action.name)
    copy.id_root = action.id_root
    
    for fcurve in action.fcurves:
        kfs = np.empty(len(fcurve.keyframe_points) << 1)
        fcurve.keyframe_points.foreach_get("co", kfs)
        kfs = kfs.reshape((-1, 2))
        _fc = copy.fcurves.new(
                fcurve.data_path,
                index = fcurve.array_index
                )
        _fc.keyframe_points.add(0)
        _kfs = kfs[
                np.logical_and(
                    kfs[:,0] >= start_frame, 
                    kfs[:,0] <= end_frame
                    )
                ]
        if shift:
            _kfs[:,0] -= (start_frame - 1)
        _fc.keyframe_points.add(_kfs.shape[0])
        _fc.keyframe_points.foreach_set("co", _kfs.ravel())
    return copy
    
action = bpy.data.actions.get("Jumping")
action_slice(action, 100, 300, shift=False)
action_slice(action, 100, 300)
```

Test run on CMU mocap file 01_01 Jumping.

Output.

```
--------------------------------------------
In: Jumping frame_range (1.0, 551.1978149414062)
Fcurves 96
Keyframes 264192
Out: Jumping.017 frame_range (100.19960021972656, 299.9988098144531)
Fcurves 96
Keyframes 96000
Elapsed time 0.1481459140777588
--------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------
In: Jumping frame_range (1.0, 551.1978149414062)
Fcurves 96
Keyframes 264192
Out: Jumping.018 frame_range (1.1996002197265625, 200.99880981445312)
Fcurves 96
Keyframes 96000
Elapsed time 0.14278960227966309
--------------------------------------------
>>>
```

Comment: Have you found a new hobby in Numpy? Nice answer...

Comment: In a way, I suppose.  Always found it a bit of a _"dark art"_  Just like pushing matrices as a "see the light" way to transform, AFAIK there is no way to do something like above quicker without it...

Comment: This is perfect, and runs incredibly well. I was even able to add an argument to change the name of the generated action so they can be unique. Awesome answer!